# Python3: Popen with infile and outfile doesn't stop at the end of infile

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

- I want to call an interactive command line program (c++ using cin/cout).
- I want to define the input through an input file.
- I want the output to be written in an output file.
- After all the inputs inside the input file are used, the executed program should be killed, even, if it would naturally run on.
- Target machine is windows 10.

To achieve this, I tried using the following:

```
from subprocess import *
with open("input.txt", "r") as ifile:
 with open("output.txt","w") as ofile:
     p = Popen(["./example.exe"], stdin=ifile, stdout=ofile, stderr=None, universal_newlines=True )
     p.wait()
```

- I also tried it with call instead of Popen, but same result.
- I also tried p.stdin.write/ readline, but everything I came up with hangs (eg, because the exe program waits inside cin) or mashes up the order.

This is my cpp code for testing:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string inputString("");
    for (int i = 0; i< 200; ++i){
        cout << "type a number: " << endl;
        cin >> inputString;
        if(inputString == "1"){
            cout << "eins" << endl;
        } else if (inputString == "2"){
            cout << "zwei" << endl;
        } else if (inputString == "blub"){
            break;
        }
        else{
            cout << "unknown" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect this the python code to stop running, after all input lines inside the input file are used. 
Instead, the last line gets repeatedly used as input (arbitrary* number of times) or the program gets terminated in the middle.

*arbitrary: Outfile always has exactly 400 lines.

Comment: your c++ program doesn't check for neither EOF nor I/O errors. If you can't modify it, then you have to use heuristics to know when to kill the program forcefully from outside (in your Python code) e.g., feed the input manually via a pipe and kill the child process as soon as you flushed all the input (note: it won't guarantee that there weren't be unnecessary iterations in the  child process -- it is broken)